# Выход в меню в приложении на Tizen

Tags: javascript

Есть такие строки кода `function r(){e.on("keydown:always",i)}function s(){e.off("keydown:always",i)}function i(i,e){t||"exit"!==e||(t=!0,n.unload())}var t=!1
e.on("keydown:last",function(i,o){t||i.isDefaultPrevented()||"return"!==o&&"exit"!==o||(i.preventDefault(),r(),e.execute("app:confirm","Закрыть виджет?",function(e){s(),e&&(t=!0,tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit())}))})}(t,o),Ge=function(n,i,t,e,r){"use strict"`
Что исправить для того, чтобы не закрывать и выходить в меню.За выход в меню отвечает вот такой код

```
case"blue":e.trigger("app:showFilms")это синяя кнопка на пульте
```

Comment: о_О вы прикалываетесь?

Comment: В смысле? я не программист поэтому и прошу помощи.В чем тут прикол?

Comment: прикол в том, что в куске минифицированного кода нереально что-то разобрать.

Comment: 2024 строки кода вы предлагаете сюда залить?

Comment: Вот сам скрипт [ссылка]http://widget.torrent-tv.ru/js/app-package.js